# How can I evaluate the top level model in HMM?

Tags: python, hidden-markov-model, precision-recall

I have a python code that is using the top level model which combines the gesture and threshold model (HMM).  then it evaluates it.  actually my task is to implement spotting performance evaluation like precision and recall but actually I didn't understand how to implement them because as far as I understood for the precision formula  = TP/TP+FP and my data to evaluate isn't a binary one and I didn't understand how to implement it.
any help please ?